# How to import a component and all its deps?

Tags: vue.js

Here's a script where I'm trying to import a component and use its dependencies in the template. In other words, I want to locally register a component `FooComponent` and use `SharedComponent` in the template of `BarComponent`. In angular 2 -- one registers a module and gets access to all deps of that module. How would you implement something like this in vue?

```js
    const SharedComponent = {
      template: '<div>Shared component!</div>'
    }
    const FooComponent = new Vue({
      components: {
        'app-shared': SharedComponent 
      }
    })
    const BarComponent = new Vue({
      el: '#outlet',
      template: '<app-shared></app-shared>',
      components: {
        'foo-component': FooComponent 
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="outlet"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how it works in Vue compared to Angular. You can't make a Vue instance (your `FooComponent`) a component inside another instance. Besides, in order to use component in a template, you need to import it directly.

So, you can either:

1. Make `FooComponent` just a component, not an instance, and do something like this:

```js
const SharedComponent = { //component
  template: '<div>Shared component!</div>'
}
const FooComponent = { // component
  template: '<app-shared></app-shared>', // you import it here, so you can use it inside a template
  components: {
    'app-shared': SharedComponent 
  }
}
const BarComponent = new Vue({ // instance
  el: '#outlet',
  template: '<foo-component></foo-component>', // again, use the component which you've imported
  components: {
    'foo-component': FooComponent 
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="outlet"></div>
```

2. Use `SharedComponent` directly:

```js
const SharedComponent = {
  template: '<div>Shared component!</div>'
}

const BarComponent = new Vue({
  el: '#outlet',
  template: '<app-shared></app-shared>',
  components: {
    'app-shared': SharedComponent 
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="outlet"></div>
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help.